# Saves icon not loading with new answers

Tags: bug, live-refresh, saves, ajax

When on a question page, if answers are posted *after* loading that page, a button appears (for example):

> 1 new answer to this question

Clicking this loads the new answer(s), but they don't show the *Saves* bookmark icon.

---

A workaround is to simply reload the page.

Comment: @V2Blast I've also considered adding [tag:live-refresh] tag but the bug isn't with the live refresh itself (which it responsible for showing the "1 new answer" banner), but rather with what happens when it's clicked, i.e. the AJAX code running on the client side and fetching the new answer(s).